# Checking if a key in a dictionary also exists as a value, and if so, consolidating them?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use a Python dictionary to create a taxonomical structure out of an Excel spreadsheet.  Each entity has several sub-entities, and I want to represent this as a nested Python dictionary.

My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Entity              Includes
Account             Customer Account
Account             Corporate Account
Account             Account Balance
Account Balance     Exposure
```

So on and so forth.

I load the file into a DataFrame and then create a dictionary through Pandas' groupby-split-apply:

```
df = pd.read_excel('taxonomy_file.xlsx')

groupby = dict(df.groupby('Entity')['Includes'].apply(list))
```

My resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
{'Account': ['Customer Account',
             'Corporate Account',
             'Account Balance'],
 'Account Balance': ['Exposure']}
```

My desired result is to write something that will detect that 'Account Balance' is both a key and a value, and to convert the 'Account Balance' that is a value to one that is both a value and a key for 'Exposure':

```
{'Account': ['Customer Account',
             'Corporate Account',
             {'Account Balance': 'Exposure'}]
```

Ultimately, there is not a huge amount of terms I need to deal with but I would much prefer to not do it manually.  I have tried doing something like the following just to test that it is possible to detect both a key and a value in separate parts of a dictionary:

```
for k, v in groupby.items():
    if k in v:
        print(k)
```

But no luck, since it is only searching if each key exists in that key's value list.  I'm mostly looking for any pointers or thoughts on how to approach this problem, or if I am thinking about it wrong.

Comment: One question is that: If `Account Balance` also eixsts in other row, at 2nd columns, how do you treat it? Duplicate them in every key-value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your file is the conversion of a tree structure (but it may be any directed graph). The first idea is to distinguish between the references and the roots: a root is a key that is never a value, whereas a reference is a key that is also a value:

```
all_values = set(x for xs in d.values() for x in xs)
refs = all_values & set(d.keys())
```

We also need a function that searches a key in refs and returns a new dict if that key was found:

```
def resolve_ref(key):
    if key in refs:
        return {key: [resolve_ref(x) for x in d[key]]}
    else:
        return key
```

This function is obviously recursive, since we need to resolve refs, refs of refs, .... At the end, there is no ref in the values.

The last part is the creation of a dict having only non ref keys, and resolve all the refs in the values:

```
{k: [resolve_ref(x) for x in vs] for k, vs in d.items() if k not in refs}
```

Let's put the blocks together and try on a more complex example:

```
def consolidate(d):
    all_values = set(x for xs in d.values() for x in xs)
    refs = all_values & set(d.keys())

    def resolve_ref(key):
        if key in refs:
            return {key: [resolve_ref(x) for x in d[key]]}
        else:
            return key

    return {k: [resolve_ref(x) for x in vs] for k, vs in d.items() if k not in refs}
```

Example:

```
d = {'Account': ['Customer Account',
             'Corporate Account',
             'Account Balance'],
    'Account Balance': ['Exposure'],
    'Exposure': ['Foo', 'Bar']} 

print(consolidate(d))
# {'Account': ['Customer Account', 'Corporate Account', {'Account Balance': [{'Exposure': ['Foo', 'Bar']}]}]}
```

*Note:* cycles will be removed, because if there was a root of the cycle, it would also a be value, hence a ref and not a root.

```
d = {'Foo': ['Bar'],
    'Bar': ['Baz'],
    'Baz': ['Foo']}
print(consolidate(d))
# {}
```

Comment: Amazing.  This works wonderfully for my use case.  Thank you for your assistance!